# Will just holding a catalyst help my spell damage?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I use hex magic and I have a staff and a chime but so far I only need to use a staff.

Will merely holding the chime in the other hand make the spell damage from my staff stronger? I figure it might since the chime has dark magic stat, but I'm not sure if it contributes to my character or just to the chime's spells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catalysts and Chimes only affect the spell they are used to cast; having one in your off hand will not change the effect.

You can test this by checking the damage you do with your hexes with the chime in your offhand, compared to having a shield or nothing there. The damage will be the same either way.